# UML diagram (Class Diagram) of whole Spring project in STS

Tags: spring, rest, class-diagram

I have developed a REST API's Project and I want to draw a class diagram for every API individually. I have downloaded the eclipse plugin of PlantUML but this doesn't generate the complete API class diagram it only generates for each class. Is there any tool which can help me to generate the class diagram for each API. I need a class diagram having all required classes involved in an API with proper relationships like association, inheritance, etc.

for example, I have created one myself but I am not able to verify it for correction from anywhere.

In this class diagram, a request for client information (list of items) comes to ClientProfileContoller and ClientProfileContoller calls a ClientProfileService method which returns a List of objects of ClientProfileVO after performing respective DB Operations. ClientProfileContoller uses ResponseUtility class to perform common operations and at last List of ClientProfileVO objects are added to BaseResponse using its setData(List) method and BaseResponse is returned to ClientProfileContoller. ClientProfileContoller sends BaseResponse as a final response to the client.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to use a recent open-source project based on the use of JDT named : Spoon, now [available on Github](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon).

It offers a simple, intuitive API to program your own Java analysis and even more.

As a proof of concept, during my bachelor we were introduced to this API to do many (semi)automated refactoring (mainly for monoliths migration to microservices) and automated [Control Flow Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph) analysis